# Alias git branches to replace "master" with "main"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-alias

I work on a bunch of different repos - many of them use `master`, and many of them use `main`.

I also have various shell aliases set up for git commands, e.g. `gcm` for `git checkout master`.

The problem is that I cannot use these aliases on repos where `master` doesn't exist. It's obviously not a big deal, because I just need to type out the command manually in that case, but it's slightly annoying.

I am wondering if there's a way I can "alias" branches in git, so when I say `git push origin master` it can just automatically replace that with main.

Comment: Could you check `git config init.defaultBranch`? It could default to master if empty.

Comment: You can set per-repository aliases, stored in `.git/config`. A little more work to add the correct alias to each repository, but the alias definitions themselves are much simpler.

Comment: Thank you @chepner this is probably what I would prefer to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a repository that has `main`, but not `master`, the simplest is to create a *branch alias* `master` that points to `main`:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/main
```

This gives the following list of branches (for example):

```
$ git branch -a
* main
  master -> main
  side
```

Now everytime your commands reference `master` they apply to `main`. Even when you push `master`, the actual target is `main`:

```
$ git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 241 bytes | 241.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ../gitupstream
   f57e131..15c1aad  master -> main
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution, but I can't get it to work. Even after manually creating `master` on a repo which previously just had `main`, this `symbolic-ref` command doesn't cause the result you show (the `master -> main` mapping).

Comment: What do you mean with "manually create `master`"? There must not be a branch `master`, neither in the local repository nor in the remote. After the `symbolic-ref` command in the local repository, there is just a, let's call it "symbolic link", named `master` that acts like it were the branch `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `git show-ref -q` to check if the branch exists:

```
alias gcm='git show-ref -q --heads main && git checkout main || git checkout master'
```

You could write a shell function to return the default branch name:

```
default_branch_name() {
    git show-ref -q --heads main && echo main || echo master
}

alias gcm="git checkout $(default_branch_name)"
```

That probably simplifies writing additional aliases.

---

The above assumes only two possible names for the primary branch. You could of course check for more:

```
default_branch_name() {
    for name in master trunk main; do
        git show-ref -q --heads $name && break
    done

    echo $name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like [j6t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73246036/1256452), but note that when you run `git clone`, the *default branch* in the origin repository, after mapping to remote-tracking name, becomes the `origin/HEAD` symbolic-reference name.  So you could use `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` to discover whether this is `refs/remotes/origin/master`, `refs/remotes/origin/main`, or some other value.

Using that result, you can then choose whether to use the name `main` or `master` or some other value.

For repositories where the origin's default branch is, e.g., `develop`, this means you might resolve to `develop`.  If that's what you want, that's good.

You can combine these ideas: after `git clone` (perhaps *instead of* `git clone`), run a script that reads:

```
#! /bin/sh
rhead=$(git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name origin/HEAD) || {
    echo "can't figure out default, not creating symbolic name"
    exit 1
}
rhead=${rhead#refs/remotes/origin/}
case "$rhead" in
master) ;; # do nothing
*)
    git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master "refs/heads/$rhead"
    echo "master -> $rhead"
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

(note: the above is entirely untested).

Comment: This is useful for scripting in repos in bulk, but personally I am just working with a few repos (maybe up to a dozen) so this kind of automation is probably unnecessary. I can see it being helpful for other use cases though. Thanks for putting in the work to write the script.